# Multi Apple Push Notifications with image at the same time

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm sending two push notifications with thumbnails at the same time in APNs.
But the two images are sometimes reversed, even though they are sent separately. When this happens, one of the images is not displayed.

[Image: apns_with_thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrCKG.png)

It happens in both os version iOS 13 and 14 but 13 is more frequency to happen.

Have anyone ever had this kind of problem?

Comment: Are you sending them concurrently? Maybe this is the problem. If you want to assert the order then you need to wait for APNS response for sending the first push before sending the second

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
Do you mean that APNS processes the messages and images of the notifications received separately?
Unfortunately, I use a worker to notify asynchronously, so it's hard to get an apns response.

Comment: Well then it would make sense to make one worker for sending both notifications and make them synchronous within the worker instead of two concurrent workers. I would also advise against sending two notifications at once for one user action and instead think how you can make one notification for one action. Maybe even an actionable notification with two different actions

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your advice was very useful for me.
I agree with making one notification for one action.
I'll consider it in my implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I found an issue my implementation in rendering and fixed, so it was not os's bug.